# How to source a script with args within tclsh

Tags: tcl

As far as I know, the source command only accepts the name of the script. Is there any workaround to source a script with any number of arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set argv [list your parameters go here]
source myscript.tcl
```